# Is even asking whether two eatables are different in terms of nutrition off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115504/what-is-the-difference-between-white-and-black-mustard-seeds) and got it closed.

Let X and Y are two substances. Is it off-topic to ask whether X and Y are nutritionally different or not.

The answer can be either yes or no. I am not asking for further details.

I got the following feedback

> Questions on **nutrition** or requests for medical advice are off-topic
> here; you should contact a qualified medical professional instead.

Is my question closed solely based on the reason that I am asking whether they are nutritionally different or not?

If I change my question like `In which aspect both X and Y are different` then does it become on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

If you ask about the differences, answers about the “nutritional benefits” - as phrased in your original question - would be off topic (as are questions, as you learned earlier).

They properties **from a cook’s perspective** would be on topic, e.g. different pungency due to different average content of mustard oils. Once the question (or answer) debates the health effects, it becomes off topic.